# bundle install error w find i18n-0.5.0 in any of the sources

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm trying to get a friends project running I got the code from heroku and then ran bundle install with the idea of then running rake db:migrate:

```
$ bundle install
Fetching source index for http://rubygems.org/
Could not reach rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/
Could not find i18n-0.5.0 in any of the sources
```

But it doesn't work. Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

```
Could not reach rubygems repository http://rubygems.org/
```

If you are having trouble connecting to rubygems.org then it's not possible for bundler to get the gems you need. Chances are you have no other sources where it is attempting to get gems from so you get the error it can't find any.

Verify you can reach rubygems.org and troubleshoot why bundler is unable to reach it. You could have a networking block preventing the connection.

btw what happens if you try:

```
$ gem install i18n
```

if you get the same error your machine is keeping you from hitting the rubygems repository.

Comment: I can hit rubygems.org w/o issue in the browser and with a ping in the terminal

Comment: $ gem install i18n
ERROR:  http://rubygems.org/ does not appear to be a repository
ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'i18n' (>= 0) in any repository

Comment: It appears something is incorrect in your rubygems setup. what version of gem do you have? $ gem --version